# Send me an e-mail whenever someone logs in via SSH

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to configure sshd so that it sends me an e-mail whenever someone logs in via SSH?

Comment: Any particular reason you want this instead of, say, a webpage displaying current status or a summary at the end of the day?

Answer (score 3):

Sshd itself won't do this for you, but you could probably accomplish what you want using the `pam_exec` module (assuming that you've got SSH using `PAM`).  Something like this might work (in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`):

```
session optional pam_exec.so /path/to/your/script
```

You could also watch `/var/log/secure` (or your local equivalent) for messages sshd logs when someone logs in, and trigger and email based on that.

You could also probably hack something together using the `ForceCommand` option in sshd.  You would have `ForceCommand` run a script that would send the email and then use the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable to run the user's shell (or whatever other command they were attempting to run). I only mention this because it might work, not because I think it's a good idea.

Comment: +1 for pam_exec, the nicest way to introduce session "jobs" that aren't really part of the user's shell.

Answer (score 2):

You could append this to the end of /etc/profile

```
/bin/bash -c 'HN=`/bin/hostname`; IP=`/bin/hostname -i`; /bin/bash -c "/bin/hostname -i; /bin/hostname; echo; /usr/bin/who --ips; echo; /usr/bin/who --all" | /usr/bin/mailx -s "LOGIN ALERT - $HN ($IP)" root'
```

This will email root with a list of logged in users everytime bash (the user's shell) is started.

Comment: That's unnecessarily long and complex and includes redundant commands. Also, there's no reason I can think of that you'd need to use `bash -c` (twice no less!) since `/etc/profile` is already being executed by the shell and there's nothing Bash-specific in what you posted (it might have to be changed if the user's shell is csh or something). If you need to group commands to be piped into `mail` just do `{ cmd; cmd; cmd; } | mail`.

Comment: There are some automatically set variables you could make use of without calling `hostname` (four times!). And `hostname -i` gives me "127.0.0.1" which isn't very useful. In any case, it should be made conditional so local logins aren't included in order to fit what the OP probably wants.

Comment: Although your specific example is horrible, this is generally the best solution. However, never modify /etc/profile. Just create your own script in /etc/profile.d/.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [swatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swatch/) (which is designed to watch logfiles and send emails with lines matching regexps) to monitor `/var/log/secure` (or wherever your OS logs ssh logins), looking for lines like

```
sshd[xxxxx]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user foo by (uid=0)
```

and sending mails accordingly.